# Structuring flat html structure into a tree

Tags: html, scheme, data-mining

Given an html page with heading tags such `h1`, `h2` through `h6` and `p` tags construct a hierarchical structure. A super problem of this problem is explained in [Heading Based Sectional Hierarchy Identification for HTML Documents](https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~gungort/papers/Heading-Based%20Sectional%20Hierarchy%20Identification%20for%20HTML%20Documents.pdf).

I've written the following code, how can I improve it:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 match))


(define-syntax test-check
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ title tested-expression expected-result)
     (begin (format #t "** Checking ~a\n" title)
            (let* ((expected expected-result)
                   (produced tested-expression))
              (if (not (equal? expected produced))
                  (begin (format #t "*** Expected: ~s\n" expected)
                         (format #t "*** Computed: ~s\n" produced))))))))


(define doc '((h . 1) p (h . 2) p p (h . 2) p p (h . 1) p p))

;; (define out ((div
;;               (h1 "title 1")
;;               (p "paragraph 1#1")
;;               (div
;;                (h2 "title 1.1")
;;                (p paragraph 

(define pp pretty-print)

(define (append-paragraph tree)
  (match tree
    ('() '(p))
    (('p . rest) (cons 'p (append-paragraph rest)))
    (((('h . level) . rest)) (list (cons (cons 'h level) (append-paragraph rest))))
    ((head . rest) (cons head (append-paragraph rest)))
    (_ (display "fuu ") (pp tree) (error tree))))

(test-check "append-paragraph: null"
  (append-paragraph '())
  '(p))

(test-check "append-paragraph: single paragraph"
  (append-paragraph '(p))
  '(p p))

(test-check "append-paragraph: single heading"
  (append-paragraph '(((h . 1))))
  '(((h . 1) p)))

(test-check "append-paragraph: paragraph followed by a single heading"
  (append-paragraph '(p ((h . 1))))
  '(p ((h . 1) p)))

(test-check "append-paragraph: paragraph followed by a heading with a paragraph"
  (append-paragraph '(p ((h . 1) p)))
  '(p ((h . 1) p p)))

(test-check "append-paragraph: nested 0"
  (append-paragraph '(p ((h . 1) p) ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p p))))
  '(p ((h . 1) p) ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p p p))))

(test-check "append-paragraph: nested 1"
  (append-paragraph '(p ((h . 1) p) ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p p) ((h . 2) p)) ((h . 1))))
  '(p ((h . 1) p) ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p p) ((h . 2) p)) ((h . 1) p)))

(test-check "append-paragraph: nested 2"
  (append-paragraph '(p ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p) ((h . 2) p ((h . 3) p) ((h . 3) p)))))
  '(p ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p) ((h . 2) p ((h . 3) p) ((h . 3) p p)))))

(define (append-heading tree level)
  (match tree
    ('() `(((h . ,level))))
    (((('h . other) . rest))
     (if (eq? other level)
         `(((h . ,level) . ,rest) ((h . ,level)))
         `(((h . ,other) . ,(append-heading rest level)))))
    ((head . rest) `(,head . ,(append-heading rest level)))))

(test-check "append-heading: null"
  (append-heading '() 1)
  '(((h . 1))))

(test-check "append-heading: append h1 to h1"
  (append-heading '(((h . 1))) 1)
  '(((h . 1)) ((h . 1))))

(test-check "append-heading: append h1 to h1>h2"
  (append-heading '(((h . 1) ((h . 2) p))) 1)
  '(((h . 1) ((h . 2) p)) ((h . 1))))

(test-check "append-heading: append h2 to h1>h2"
  (append-heading '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p))) 2)
  '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p) ((h . 2)))))

(test-check "append-heading: append h3 to h1>h2"
  (append-heading '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p))) 3)
  '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p ((h . 3))))))

(test-check "append-heading: append h3 to h1>h2"
  (append-heading '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p))) 3)
  '(((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p ((h . 3))))))


(define (parse doc)
  (let loop ((doc doc)
             (out '()))
    (match doc
      ('() out)
      (('p . rest) (loop rest (append-paragraph out)))
      ((('h . level) . rest) (loop rest (append-heading out level))))))


(test-check "parse: paragraph"
  (parse '(p))
  '(p))

(test-check "parse 0"
  (parse '(p (h . 1) p (h . 2) p (h . 2) p (h . 3) p (h . 3) p (h . 1) p))
  '(p ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p) ((h . 2) p ((h . 3) p) ((h . 3) p))) ((h . 1) p)))

(test-check "parse 1"
  (parse '(p (h . 1) p (h . 2) p (h . 2) p (h . 3) p (h . 3) p p))
  '(p ((h . 1) p ((h . 2) p) ((h . 2) p ((h . 3) p) ((h . 3) p p)))))
```

I read I can use zipper or cursors. Can the implementation of cursors be simpler in my case?

Answer (score 1):

If you map h1, h2, h3 and p to integers representation their priority you can solve the problem in a simpler way.

```
def abc(l,s=0):
    p = [l[s]]
    s = s + 1
    while s < len(l):
        if l[s] <= p[0]:
            break
        ll, s = abc(l,s)
        if len(ll) == 1:
            p.append(ll[0])
        else:
            p.append(ll)
    return p,s

print(abc([0,1,2,2]))
print(abc([0,1,8,8,2,8,8,2,8,4,1,2]))
```

This use mutation, but you can adapt it to work without mutation.